# Facebook blocking my website URLs

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share a link of my Wordpress website on Facebook but I'm seeing this error.

The Error:
[image]

When I tried to check what's wrong with the link in Facebook Debugger i saw this.
Facebook Debugger:
[image]

Please help me what to do as I'm not good in seeing through this problem.

Comment: Is your site/domain serving malware or other malicious content?

Comment: Click the Let us know link and then wait

Comment: Already tried scanning it with Sucuri and reported on let us know. But nothing was detected by the malware scanner and no progress has happened even after reporting the problem to Facebook.

Comment: are you still having this problem
If yes, install the Facebook plugin on your site then fill out the fields in the plugin